# Unit Test error for Angular using Karma / Jasmine for Router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am getting the following error when unit testing my Angular application, which is: Error: Unexpected value 'Router' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.” Any idea's what it could be? Code so far is:

**header.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent],
      imports: [ 
        FontAwesomeModule, 
        RouterModule,
        Router
      ],
      providers: [ AppRoutingModule],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { faHeadphones} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { PlaylistService } from '../../../services/playlist.service';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;

  constructor(private list: PlaylistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer/footer.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './components/content-area/content/content.component';
import { HomeViewComponent } from './views/home-view/home-view.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { PlaylistViewComponent } from './views/playlist-view/playlist-view/playlist-view.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './components/news/news/news.component';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    HomeViewComponent,
    PlaylistViewComponent,
    NewsComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    CarouselModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Don't understand what the downvote was for, I have tried to rectify my code and have posted only when I have needed some help!!

Comment: Why do you have Router in the imports array in your spec file?

Comment: Because I was getting a static injection error

Comment: You should be using [RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) in your unit testing specs. You can import that like this: `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';` Using that, you don't need to include RouterModule and Router in you specs.

Comment: Thanks that worked, could you post answer and then I can accept..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule) in your unit testing specs.

You can import that like this:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

Using that, you don't need to include RouterModule and Router in you specs. Example spec below.

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AppComponent ],
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```